# Google App Script .lastrow needs to be added but I keep getting error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script where it copies and pastes data into another sheet. This all works well. Except for the paste part.

Now it pastes in a certain range "A3". But I want it to paste onto the last row.

This is the current script:

```
/**
* This is a placemarker function used to call the importRange.
* You can call importRange() from any function or just use this  one for your project.
*/
function runsies() {
 
  importRange(
    "1ZcNEqM-xqRE04LLZM8N_AhuMDQjx1DQKSjfYcCMxwsA",  //Source ID -  e.g. "14QBa3ID3EWbK3FNReNUn5nlJwQFQR6l91zODzZTd6SA"
    "Product-analyse!F93:L142", // Source Range - e.g. "Task List!A2:G"
    "189hJTiUlwubZdeN1HZ9n98U-gdaGdFSAu1-ARvlGMKo", // Destination ID - e.g. "14QBa3ID3EWbK3FNReNUn5nlJwQFQR6l91zODzZTd6SA"
    "RawDataCopyPaste!A3" // Destination Range Start - e.g. "Sheet1!B3"
  );
 
};
 
/**
* Imports range data from one Google Sheet to another.
* @param {string} sourceID - The id of the source Google Sheet.
* @param {string} sourceRange - The Sheet tab and range to copy.
* @param {string} destinationID - The id of the destination Google Sheet.
* @param {string} destinationRangeStart - The destintation location start cell as a sheet name and cell.
*/
function importRange(sourceID, sourceRange, destinationID, destinationRangeStart){
 
  // Gather the source range values
  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange)
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();
 
  // Get the destiation sheet and cell location.
  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destStartRange.getSheet();
 
 
  // Get the full data range to paste from start range.
  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
      destStartRange.getRow(),
      destStartRange.getColumn(),
      sourceVals.length,
      sourceVals[0].length
    );
  
  // Paste in the values.
  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);
 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

Comment: To be honest with you, you can't if you want to use `importRange()` because the destination address is hard coded into the call to that function.  You need to get the destination spreadsheet, destination sheet and the destination sheet's last row and construct the `destinationRangeStart` string.  Which defeats the purpose of `importRange()`

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);
```

...with code that finds the first free row in the destination sheet, and appends the data starting there. One way to do that is to use the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function, like this:

```
  appendRows_(destSheet, sourceVals);
```